# How to close a simple modal dialog on a button click?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, modal-dialog

Here i am trying to close a modal dialog on a button click but it is not closing the dialog.Here is my code

```
function closemodal() {
    alert("true");
    $.modal.close();
    return false;
}
```

and

```
protected void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "ScriptRegistration", "closemodal();", true);
}
```

i need to call a javascript function and after that i need to close that dialog..Any suggestion??

EDIT:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#MainContent_uscRetailParameters_btnOK').click(function (e) {
            closemodal();
            return false;
        });
        function closemodal() {
            $.modal.close();
        }
    });
```

EDIT 2:

```
  $('#CusCatPOPUP .basic').click(function (e) 
{ 
$('#CusCatPOPUP-content').modal(); 
return false; 
}
);
```

Comment: Just add the function inside the click function? What modal are you using?

Comment: http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

Comment: remember to accept your answers when answered. Can see you have dozen open, which are answered correctly. Else you can't create new threads, and people can't see if the question was answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing the point:

```
$('#MainContent_uscRetailParameters_btnOK').click(function (e) {
    MyFunctionCall();   //i.e. call you function here
    $.modal.close();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: no i need to close that dialog box through this function closemodal()

Comment: this $.modal.close(); is not working while calling closemodal() function

Answer (score 1):

Might be an error elsewhere, check your browser console.

Created an example: http://jsfiddle.net/eTnJF/

With code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.open').click( function() {
        $('#modal').modal();
    });

    $('.close').click( function() {
        closemodal();
        return false;
    });

    function closemodal() {
        alert("true");
        $.modal.close();
    }
});
```

Which works fine :)

Comment: i am using ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal

Comment: Tried the link? Also remember to have an ready function around it. Updated the code.

Comment: Where do you open the "modal" box? And are you sure the modal script is included? Because your code is fine, so the error must be somewhere else.

Comment: See: http://jsfiddle.net/eTnJF/1/ ... posted in your code, and it's working. So it's something else, like an other script making an error, or not including the simplemodal script. You are using a local version right?

Comment: Well i can't really debug, when all the code you pasted are working :(

Comment: in IE getting Microsoft JScript runtime error: '$.modal' is null or not an object

Comment: Which would normally mean it can't find the simplemodal plugin :/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply close the modalpopup then the javascript code is.

```
var mpu = $find('ModalPopupExtender1');
mpu.hide();
```

Hope it helps.

thanks
Kamran